# Vue.js: Global event bus is failing to catch the event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a global event bus to be emitted from `Source.vue` to be caught in `Destination.vue`. The latter component has to run a function when the event is caught.

`Source.vue`:

```
.then(() => {
    eventBus.$emit("fireMethod");
})
```

`Destination.vue`:

```
updated() {
  eventBus.$on("fireMethod", () => {
    this.reqMethod();
  });
}
```

`main.js`:

```
export const eventBus = new Vue();
```

I have also imported the main.js file in both of the components. But that doesn't seem to work as the event is not caught at all. What's wrong here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's not enough context in your question to determine the problem. When is the code in `Source.vue` executed? And when is `Destination.vue` mounted? Any particular reason to use the `updated` hook here (e.g., instead of `mounted`)?

Comment: Hey @tony19, the code in `Source.vue` is executed after certain actions have been performed in the database(deletion in this case). Here `Destination.vue` displays that data so I want it to get updated every time there is a change in the database without me visiting that component. That doesn't happen if I use the `mounted` hook so I had to use the `updated` hook

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't clarify the timeline of when `Destination` is listening to the event relative to the event occurring in `Source`. It's possible `Destination` registers for the event *after* `Source` already emitted it. Note that events aren't queued for listeners. Can you provide a reproducible example (e.g., in Codesandbox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated hook runs after data changes on your component and the DOM re-renders. Hence on the initial render your event listener is not registered as the event is not triggered at that time.

Kindly go through this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saqueib/pLvyhskp/) to get a clear idea about vue components life cycle.

Hence in Destination.vue:

Your event hook should be mounted and not updated.

```
mounted() {
  eventBus.$on("fireMethod", () => {
    this.reqMethod();
  });
}
```

Comment: But I want `reqMethod` to run every time the dom is updated due to the actions of `Source.vue`

Comment: you just need to emit the event from actions in source.vue whenever your data is updating.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer so the question would be closed.

Answer (score 0):

To register global event bus you can use this in your `main.js`

```
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue();        //global event bus
```

And then in your components use it like

```
//on emit
this.$eventHub.$on('your-event',function(){});

//to emit
this.$eventHub.$emit('your-event',data);
```